# Fixed point of a group action

Tags: group-actions, fixed-point-theorems, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ be the product of countably many real lines.

Assume that a finitely generated group $\Gamma$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ (linearly and continuously) and there is a nonempty convex compact $\Gamma$-invariant subset $K$.

Is it true that $\Gamma$ has a fixed point in $K$?

(In my case, the group $\Gamma$ is NOT commutative and it is NOT amenable.)

*Please help.*

Comment: Hi! Can you give an example of a group acting linearly on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and is not amenable? Otherwise there should be trivial examples.

Comment: @Bombyxmori any finitely generated group can act by permuting the coordinates.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: Thank you a lot for explaining.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{R}^\infty$? I understand it's an (infinite countable)-dimensional vector space, but what is required on its topology? I understood it carries the product topology.

Comment: @YCor: Maybe I am a bit naive, but I think on $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ the usual limit topology and product topology coincide. So moving sequences like $(0,0,0\cdots, 1,0,0\cdots)$ converges to $0$ in this topology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so. Let $\Gamma$ be the free group with 2 generators. It has a natural action on the boundary $\partial\Gamma$ and therefore on the space of probability measures on the boundary as well. The latter action is affine and has no fixed points (no invariant measures on the boundary). Let us now realize this action as an action on $\mathbb R^\infty$ by choosing a sufficiently big $\Gamma$-invariant family of test functions on the boundary (so that they separate probability measures). For instance, for any two distinct group elements $g,h\in\Gamma$ let $f_{g,h}$ be the indicator function of the shadow of $h$ as seen from $g$. Then any probability measure $\mu$ on the boundary is uniquely determined by the collection of the integrals $\langle f_{g,h},\mu\rangle$, and the action of the group on $\mu$ amounts to permuting the values of the test integrals.

Comment: I mean the subset $K$ of $\mathbb R^\infty$ which consists of integrals of test functions against probability measures. It is convex, compact and nonempty.

Comment: Is it a standard example, does it have a name?

Comment: No - I haven't seen anything like this before.